# On the Wedderburn component of a group algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, group-rings

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field, where $q$ is a prime power.
Let $\mathbb{F}_qG$ be a finite semisimple group algebra.

Then Wedderburn decomposition theorem implies that $\mathbb{F}_qG$ is direct sum of matrix rings over division rings, i.e.,$$\mathbb{F}_qG\cong \oplus_{i=1}^t M(n_i, \mathbb{F}_{q_i}).$$

Here $\mathbb{F}_{q_i}$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, $n_i\geq 1$ and $t\geq 1$ are positive integers.

**Given**: Suppose that $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ is such that
$$\mathbb{F}_qG\cong \oplus_{i=1}^t M(n_i, \mathbb{F}_{q}).$$
This means $q_i=q$ for each $i$.

Let $q'\neq q$ be another prime power such that the group algebra $\mathbb{F}_{q'}G$ is again semisimple.

Suppose that  $M\left(n, \mathbb{F}_{(q')^r}\right)$ is a Wedderburn component of the group algebra  $\mathbb{F}_{q'}G$ for some $r\geq 2$ and any positive integer $n$.

Then I want to show that $M\left(n, \mathbb{F}_{q}\right)$ must be a Wedderburn component of the group algebra  $\mathbb{F}_qG$.

I have tried various examples and found this result true. Please help me to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I just reminded you that $\mathbb{F}_qG$ is semisimple if and only if $p$ and $|G|$ are co-prime.

Now for the question. The idea is to tensor with $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$. It's easy to see that $$\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}G =\mathbb{F}_qG\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_q}\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}\cong \bigoplus M(n_i,\overline{\mathbb{F}_q})$$ On the other hand, we get $$\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}G =\mathbb{F}_{q'}G\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_{q'}}\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}\cong \bigoplus M(m_i,\mathbb{F}_{(q')^{r_i}}\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_{q'}}\overline{\mathbb{F}_q})$$
Now using that $\mathbb{F}_{(q')^{r_i}}\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_{q'}}\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}\cong \overline{\mathbb{F}_q}^{r_i} $, we can get
$$M(m_i,\mathbb{F}_{(q')^{r_i}}\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_{q'}}\overline{\mathbb{F}_q})\cong M(m_i,\overline{\mathbb{F}_q})^{r_i}$$ From the uniqueness of the decomposition, we get that every $m_i$ is a some $n_i$.

For the claim about the tensor product of the fields look at [étale algebres](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_algebra) or this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452743/separable-extension-and-tensor-product).

Comment: Can you please tell some references where I can get to study the properties of tensor products mentioned by you?

Comment: Most of the properties are standards like $(A\oplus B)\otimes C  = (A\otimes C)\oplus (B\otimes C)$. Every algebra book introducing tensor products (like algebra by Lang) will prove them. I also used that $M(n,A)\otimes_{B}C\cong M(n, A\otimes_{B}C)$, it's a nice exercise proving this.